# Is Pickwick green tea deceffeinated?

Tags: tea, caffeine

I am referring to this brand: [http://www.amazon.com/Pickwick-Green-Tea-Original-Packages/dp/B003YBNJH8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YBNJH8)

The box doesn't say anything. I drank several and while I felt weird, my pulse was normal. I can't find any info on this tea and their website is in non-english languages only. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Green tea contains caffeine naturally. Here is a reference for general amounts in beverages [Mayoclinic Nutrition](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/caffeine/art-20049372). As Memj said, Decaf products are generally labeled as such.

From the [Pickwick.nl](http://www.pickwick.nl/thee/groene-thee/original/) using Google translate:

> Have you ever heard of theine? That's just another name for caffeine
>   in black, green and white tea. But how much caffeine now actually
>   contains a cup of tea? A cup of black tea contains approximately 30 mg
>   of caffeine. At an average cup of coffee is 85 mg. Rather a time no
>   caffeine? Choose one or Rooibos herbal blend.

It's not specific for their green tea, but does say to choose herbal blends if you don't want caffeine.

Answer (score 2):

Caffeine content in tea depends on the cultivar, method of cultivation, and age of the leaves (shade-grown buds and young leaves having the most), but not the general type (black/green) of the tea.

Black tea is withered/oxidized before being dried, whereas green tea is usually roasted (for Chinese tea) or steamed (Japanese). This processing does not significantly change the caffeine content. Any difference between black and green tea produced from the same leaves is due to differences in brewing - green tea is usually steeped for a shorter time than black.

Shade-grown tea is very expensive (usually grown for matcha or gyokuro), and cheaper tea is made from the older leaves, which have the lowest amount of caffeine. It's therefore probable that this tea is naturally low in caffeine.

Comment: Do you have a source backing up your claim that older leaves have less caffeine?

Comment: http://chadao.blogspot.com/2008/02/caffeine-and-tea-myth-and-reality.html - specifically, section II ("Caffeine levels in various teas").